# how to call vue router from inside custom function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, router

I use VueCLI and i do have such code inside methods:

```
submitCheck: function () {
function authUser() {
  // returns a promise   
}
function uploadFile() {
  // also returns a promise
}

// ...

if ( error !== null ) {
    EventBus.$emit('showError', error)
} else {
    authUser()
        .then(
            function () {
                return uploadFile();
            })
        .then(
            function (data) {
                EventBus.$emit('loaderStop')
                this.$router.push('/awaiting');
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            EventBus.$emit('loaderStop')
                console.log(error)
        })
}
```

What i want to achieve is to route to /awaiting if all promises are resolved, but since i use this inside an anonymous function it doesnt have router. I am sure many coders met such a problem and needed to route from inside a function. How to do it?

Kalreg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple ways to handle this, I'd suggest you use arrow functions and learn about their differences to the other function style.

to be clear:
replace

```
function (data) {
    EventBus.$emit('loaderStop')
    this.$router.push('/awaiting');
}
```

with

```
data => {
    EventBus.$emit('loaderStop');
    this.$router.push('/awaiting');
}
```

Comment: that solution actually worked for me fine. I thought that fat arrow just shortens code, not changes reference of this.. Ugh.. people learn whole life.

Answer (score 1):

You question context is not clear enough. If the code is executed in exponent methods, you can use arrow funciton like `(agrs,...) => {...}`. Otherwise, if this is not the case, you can use [bind function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) like `(function() {}).bind(this)`. Or just import $router in your code module.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The answers from Sandro and Xhua are perfect. I just want to explain, WHY you get the error:

The problem is "this.". It refers to the parent object. So in your case "this." refers to the authUser Object and not to Vue. For your understanding: You could define `"var that = this"` outside of your authUser object and then use "`that.`" inside. Or you go for the more sophisticated solutions.

Comment: not entirely correct, the value of `this` depends on how the function is called and the calling doesn't happen here.

Comment: well, but the calling happens in the "then" function of the promise

Comment: no, that's the definition, the function gets called by the system when the promise resolves. `this` inside of that function is going to be window or undefined.